# django-nonrel google app engine fail to log in admin panel

Tags: google-app-engine, django-admin, django-nonrel

I've created a django-nonrel app on gae. Added a user (django.auth.models.User) with is_active, is_staff, is_suiperuser  all True. On localhost I login successfully, but I fail to login on GAE after deploy (I've created the same user on GAE too and it can be seen on datastore view).

But when I try to login on http://.appspot.com/admin/ it returns "Please enter a correct username and password."

Comment: Are you using the "appcfg.py runserver" command instead of App Engine launcher?

Comment: How did you add the user? The App Engine datastore isn't mirrored between development and production, so you'll likely need to add the user again in the production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick and Elliot are right. You have to use manage.py remote createsuperuser